# Python use to landscape generation

Tags: python

How to do a python script to generate landscape in a script-based way?
I would like to create a script-based generation instead of cliquing and manually adjusting of properties.

Answer (score 2):

Try the standard [ANT Landscape](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/ANT_Landscape) addon that comes with Blender.